# Ext js 4.2.2 - validation support for cellEditing

Tags: extjs

I am using cellEditing plugin to edit a particular cell in a grid. This serves my requirements really well from the UI point of view.
However, I want to add validations to the cell and prevent user from completing the edit event unless the value entered is valid. I am trying to achieve this through:

```
editor: {
    allowBlank: false,
    vtype:'customized vtype'
}
```

I am also implementing edit & beforeedit callback events. The error message & tooltip are shown correctly but even with an invalid value, you can still press enter and the callback method 'canceledit' is invoked. I do not want the edit event to be completed/canceled unless the value entered is valid.

However, if I use RowEditing plugin, the validation works as expected and edit event is not completed until the value entered is valid. This is what I need but the look and feel of cellEditing instead of RowEditing plugin more closely matches my requirements.

Is there a way I can have similar validation behavior in cellEditing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should listen to `validateedit` editor event and do your stuff there. See [validateedit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-validateedit) in docs.